# Can I use SQLPlus to execute a .sql file?

Tags: python, oracle, sqlplus

I have a .sql file with the following code:

```
delete from stalist
where stalistid=4944
/
insert into stalist
(stalistid, staid)
(select distinct 4944, staid
from staref
Where staid in(
3797,3798,
3870,4459,
3871,3872,
3876,3877,
0
))
/
commit
/
```

I would like to use Python to execute this file from SQLPlus. Is this possible? I do not have any python experience in this type of work and could use some help. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

see this tutorial: http://moizmuhammad.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/run-oracle-commands-from-python-via-sql-plus/

i.e.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

#function that takes the sqlCommand and connectString and retuns the output and #error string (if any)

def runSqlQuery(sqlCommand, connectString):

session = Popen(['sqlplus', '-S', connectString], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
session.stdin.write(sqlCommand)
return session.communicate()
```

should do it (where sqlCmmand is "@scriptname.sql").

Comment: So the script runs correctly, but the .sql isn't doing what it is supposed to do. If I open SQLPLUS and run the file within the program, it populates the oracle table correctly, but with the script the table is not populated. Any idea why this is happening? Do I need SQLPLUS open when I run the script?

Comment: i opened the file f= open('mysql.sql','rb')
cmd = f.read()
it runs successfully but ddl is not executed from sqlfile

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how to do this. You need to read the file and pass the entire string as a command.

```
(username, password, host) = ("user","password","host") 

conn_string = " %s/%s@%s "% (username,password,host)
session = Popen(['sqlplus','-S', conn_string], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
logging.info("Starting sqlplus")

sql_file = '%s/%s' % (sql_folder, file)
logging.info("Running " + sql_file)
f= open(sql_file,'r')
cmd = f.read()
session.stdin.write(cmd)

stdout, stderr = session.communicate()
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are outdated by almost a decade. Python 3.6+ has slightly easier methods of doing this (in my opinion, `subprocess.run()` is a bit cleaner because you don't have to resort to `Popen` hacking).

Here's a Python 3.9 function that will let you (1) log into SQL*Plus, (2) execute a SQL script, and (3) parameterize arguments to it:

```
def execute_sql_script_via_sqlplus():
    
    sqlplus_login_command = 'sudo sqlplus oracle_user/oracle_password'
    
    sql_script_path = '/example/path/to/some_script.sql'
    sql_script_arguments = ["foo", "bar"]

    sql_command = "@" + str(sql_script_path)

    for argument in sql_script_arguments:
        sql_command += f" {argument}"

    result = subprocess.run(
        sqlplus_login_command,
        input=sql_command,
        shell=True,
        text=True,
        capture_output=True
    )

    return result.stdout, result.stderr
```

I'll break this down a little:

- `subprocess.run(sqlplus_login_command)` represents whatever command you'd use to log into SQL*PLUS.  It doesn't necessarily have to use `-S connection_string` - especially if you have a valid local TNS configuration. This happens before we try to execute any SQL scripts.
- `sql_command` is an absolute system path to the script, which is prepended with `@`, and suffixed with a string-delimited list of arguments. These arguments are referenced within the script via `"&1"`, `"&2"`, etc. Arguments are not zero-indexed.
- `input=sql_command` fires off the actual SQL script after the initial SQL*Plus login.
- `capture_output` allows you to capture the `stdout`/`stderr`.
- `text=True` is necessary to make `input=sqlcommand` work.
- See [Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) for details on `shell=True`.